# Run Python in Atom and take user input

Tags: python, atom-editor

I created a script which just asks a user for their name and age using Python's `input()` function.

I installed the package [Script](https://atom.io/packages/script). This ran the script well but couldn’t deal with the input.

I have also tried a number of other options but haven’t had any success.

Any ideas how to build and execute scripts from within Atom? I don’t mind if it just simply saved the script and opened Pythons IDLE at a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Script Runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) can run scripts and supports input, unlike Script. It's the simplest full terminal package that I know of. To run a script, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

For more advanced usage, you might look at [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen).

Answer (score 2):

Add [Terminal-Plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus) and run the code with the `python name_file.py` command

Answer (score 0):

The [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) package gets around the input("") freeze problem by opening a terminal window and running the code in that.

Doing it within Atom has eluded me too, but this works OK.