# How to run a Python script from within Atom?

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

There are all sorts of posts on the internet about how you can run your Python script from inside Atom. Some say you have to install platformio-ide-terminal and some say atom-ide-ui replaced it. Neither of these are found when I use the Install option in Atom and search for them.

How do you set up Atom in Ubuntu to run your scripts?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Atom 1.49.0 x64.

Oh, and please don't recommend just using the terminal. I know how to do that and that's not what I'm asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [run python input user in atom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61195589/4518341)

Comment: Atom packages should be OS-independent, so it's weird that you're not finding those packages. Try using `apm` instead? i.e. `apm install platformio-ide-terminal`. The other one, `atom-ide-ui` seems to be dead as of 2 years ago.

Comment: Thanks. Very weird behavior but I came back to my computer this morning and decide to search again and both are now listed as available to install. I didn't really do anything except shut down Atom and restart it (not a computer reboot just closed, left for a day and came back and opened it up). I'll go with platformio... Is there a way to mark things solved on stackoverflow? I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Normally you would [post an answer](/help/self-answer) then [accept it](/help/accepted-answer), but since the solution was incidental to the question, I voted to close it as "no longer reproducible" instead. That's not a bad thing, it just means that the solution won't be useful for people with the same question in the future.